# How to retrieve info from database using ajax/json? (jQuery Week Calendar)

Tags: ajax, json, jquery

I'm trying to adapt the following [jQuery calendar module](https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar/wiki) to integrate it with PHP and a MySQL database. The problem I'm having is that the code loads events as such:

```
  return {
     events : [
        {
           "id":1,
           "start": new Date(year, month, day, 12),
           "end": new Date(year, month, day, 13, 30),
           "title":"Lunch with Mike"
        },
        {
           "id":2,
           "start": new Date(year, month, day, 14),
           "end": new Date(year, month, day, 14, 45),
           "title":"Dev Meeting"
        },
        {
           "id":3,
           "start": new Date(year, month, day + 1, 17),
           "end": new Date(year, month, day + 1, 17, 45),
           "title":"Hair cut"
        }
     ]
  };
```

I want to change this to an AJAX query that retrieves the events from the database. But I can't figure out exactly how to do this. So far I thought of using JSON to get the information from a separate PHP page that calls the data, but how can I manipulate the data to return a proper object?

So far I have something like this:

```
  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'test.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            //how can I copy the results to be able to return them?
        }
    });
```

And then in test.php I have something like

```
    $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM calendar;");

    $results = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
    {
       $results[] = array(
          'id' => $row['id'],
          'start' => $row['start'],
          'end' => $row['end'],
          'title' => $row['title']
       );
    }
    echo json_encode($results);
```

Keep in mind I also have to pass the start and end values through new Date().

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

if your php page is working properly, it should return an array of events. So the variable result would be that array. You can then create the structure {events: result} and pass it to your calendar.

```
success(result){
    var myData = {events: result};//now you have your data in correct format.
}
```

Comment: But the ajax call is asynchronous, so how can I get the variable to be able to use it outside the call alone?

Answer (score 1):

The key problem most people have is that the data that's coming back isn't in the format your expecting.

Try this combination:
JS File:

```
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : 'ajax_handle.php',
                dataType : 'json',
                data: { },
                success: function( jsondata ){

                    $.each( jsondata, function(i, item) {
                        alert( jsondata[i].start );
                    });

                }
            });
```

PHP File:

```
    $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM calendar;");

    $results = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
    {
       $results[] = array(
          'id' => $row['id'],
          'start' => $row['start'],
          'end' => $row['end'],
          'title' => $row['title']
       );
    }
    echo json_encode($results);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the javascript set data to your URL

```
data: '/calendar/getData.php'
```

And returned JSON should be something similar to this:

```
[{"id":1,"start":"2012-09-01T13:15:00","end":"2012-09-01T13:45:00","title":"title"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'test.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {

        $("title").html(result.title);
        $("start").html(result.start);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Ajax Request

   var result;

   ```
   $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'Service/jsonService.aspx/GetItems',
       data: "{'userID':'" + userID + "'}",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       async: false,
       error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
       },
       success: function (msj) {
          result = JSON.parse(msj.d);
       }
   });
   ```

2.Week Calendar data :

on **$calendar.weekCalendar({...** section

data: result

3.Get data from db

```
var query = (from t in dc.Calendar
                         where t.Status== 1
                             && t.UserID== userID
                         select t).ToList();

sb.Append("[");

foreach (var item in query)
{
     sb.Append(" { ");
     sb.Append("\"id\": \"" + item.ID + "\", ");
     sb.Append("\"start\": \"" + item.DateItem.Year + "-" + item.DateItem.Month + "-" + item.DateItem.Day + "T" + item.StartTime+ "\", ");
                sb.Append("\"end\": \"" + item.DateItem.Year + "-" + item.DateItem.Month + "-" + item.DateItem.Day + "T" + item.EndTime+ "\", ");
     sb.Append("\"title\": \"" + item.Title + "\"");
     sb.Append(" }, ");
}

result = sb.ToString().Substring(0, sb.ToString().Length - 2) + "]";

return result;
```